# C# app.config SecureString string can't recast as SecureString

Tags: c#, securestring

I have a SecureString in my application config, but when retriving it i can't recast the string to SecureString.

```
string UserPassword = AppSetting.Get(config, "password");
UserCredential.Password = (SecureString)UserPassword;
```

Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Security.SecureString'.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what a SecureString does. An app.config, when not encrypted, contains plaintext strings. The ConfigurationManager handles configuration values as plain strings. All a SecureString does is make sure the string it holds is not laid out contiguously in memory... When using AppSettings, one way or another, the string is in memory in plaintext at some point. Can you take a step back and explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thank you CodeCaster. I'm distributing an application around the office, that needs to login into some specific systems so i need to encrypt the passwords used in the application config.

Comment: @CodeCaster Sorry for posting Q here....Its being disabled for me.....I have a application which reads  a SecureString  . which is working everywhere except one client where the value is returning null......any idea if there is some settings in win which does that? apprecatiate your response!thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to build up a secure string by sending it each `char`:

```
var secure = new SecureString();
foreach(var c in UserPassword)
{
    secure.AppendChar(c);
}

UserCredential.Password = secure;
```

Comment: @Lee that makes very little sense. How did you do that?

Comment: Hi CodeCaster, i have saved the password in the app.config already as a SecureString but i'm having issues retrieving it.

Comment: @Lee then please show in your question how you save it.

Comment: @CodeCaster, i am using this for reference: http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file

Comment: @Lee yeah, so `SecureString password = DecryptString(AppSettings.Password)`?

Comment: @CodeCaster, thank you that did work although it's decrypting the securestring then encrypting it again, i wondered if there was a way just to cast it. I obviously miss understood how to use it correctly.

Comment: @Lee you can't just cast it, you'll have to fill it character by character as this answer shows. I can't quite find them now, but there's some resources on the web explaining what the SecureString does and how it's to be used.